# Python commands are not executing in cmd.exe

Tags: python, cmd, python-3.8

I have installed Python 3.8. It is working fine when I open the [EXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) file, but when I try to run it from command line it is not working.

For example, [I tried to find its version in cmd, but I think it is not executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7WXp.png).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Which Python did you install? The one from python.org, in cygwin, Anaconda, something else? Also, it'd be better to copy/paste the output of the terminal into a code sample block, so that it's searchable and easier to read & copy/paste from than a linked screenshot. Also, I see you're running the link from the start menu, have you tried to run it directly from whereever it was installed (e.g. `C:\Program Files`)?

Comment: What happens when you just call `python` without any suffix, and no flags? I have a habit of calling `python3` on my work-computer, which Windows 10 "helpfully" interprets that I want to search their store for Python3.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but maybe you could try declaring a Python path in the environment or global variable.

Check out the article *[Add Python to the Windows path](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)* with a resolution to the problem.